# Convertion spdlog::level::level_enum to/from nlohmann::json

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json, spdlog

With the help of [this tutorial](https://json.nlohmann.me/features/enum_conversion/) from nlohmann-json's documentation, I tried to convert a key-value pair from a JSON string to `spdlog::level::level_enum`.

With the following JSON

```json
{
  "log-level": "info",
  "log-path": "/var/log/info/"
}
```

and C++ code

```
#include "spdlog/spdlog.h"
#include "nlohmann/json.hpp"

NLOHMANN_JSON_SERIALIZE_ENUM(spdlog::level::level_enum, {
    {spdlog::level::level_enum::trace, "trace"},
    {spdlog::level::level_enum::debug, "debug"},
    {spdlog::level::level_enum::info, "info"},
    {spdlog::level::level_enum::warn, "warn"},
    {spdlog::level::level_enum::err, "err"},
    {spdlog::level::level_enum::critical, "critical"},
    {spdlog::level::level_enum::off, "off"}
})

int main()
{
    std::string input = R"({
  "log-level": "info",
  "log-path": "/var/log/info/"
}
)";
    auto json = nlohmann::json::parse(input);
    json["log-level"]. template get<spdlog::level::level_enum>();
}
```

,  I tried to convert the value of `"log-level"` (which is `"info"`) to `spdlog::level::level_enum`

But I got this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::detail::type_error'
  what():  [json.exception.type_error.302] type must be number, but is object
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I can convert `"log-level": "some-spdlog-level"` to `spdlog::level::level_enum`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See the statement in the documentation you linked to:

> NLOHMANN_JSON_SERIALIZE_ENUM() MUST be declared in your enum type's namespace (which can be the global namespace), or the library will not be able to locate it, and it will default to integer serialization.

Moving `NLOHMANN_JSON_SERIALIZE_ENUM` into the spdlog namespace fixes the problem:

```
namespace spdlog::level {
    NLOHMANN_JSON_SERIALIZE_ENUM(spdlog::level::level_enum, {
        {spdlog::level::level_enum::trace, "trace"},
        {spdlog::level::level_enum::debug, "debug"},
        {spdlog::level::level_enum::info, "info"},
        {spdlog::level::level_enum::warn, "warn"},
        {spdlog::level::level_enum::err, "err"},
        {spdlog::level::level_enum::critical, "critical"},
        {spdlog::level::level_enum::off, "off"}
    })
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ozWq3xT83

Comment: `spdlog::level::` could even be omitted, as in correct namespace [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/KvejcGv4c).

Comment: @Jarod42 yep, I was just making the minimum change to their code